# "About" box complete weirdness

Tags: swift

Here is the code for an "About" box in my Swift App:

```
@IBAction func button2Tapped() {
    if nil != NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") {
        var alert : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "App Name", message: "(c) 2014 by xxxxxxxxx", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style:.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "App Name"
        alert.message = "(c) 2014 by xxxxxxxxx"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        alert.show()
    }
}
```

App compiled for iOS7 and above.  Works perfectly in the simulator.  Works perfectly on a physical iPod Touch running iOS8, a physical iPhone 5s running iOS7.1 and a physical iPad Air running iOS7.1 (all three as development systems).

The App has been approved and is now on the App Store.  However, when I download the App from the App Store onto the two iOS7.1 test systems (the 5s and Air), the "About" box CRASHES the App!  It still works fine on the iOS8 iPod Touch.  Everything else about the App works perfectly... it's just that "About" box on 7.1.  Since it doesn't really affect the App and works when everyone updates to 8 I'm thinking I'll just let it ride, but I'd still love to know what is going on!

So to summarize, the code above works perfectly on 7.1 and 8 on physical hardware in the test environment, but crashes on 7.1 when obtained from the App Store.  I don't even see the logic in that!  Anyone have any idea why that might be happening?

On an unrelated note, I have test iAds just fine in the test environment.  Using the real App downloaded from the App Store I haven't seen an iAd yet... under either 7.1 or 8.  I wish there were some way to know if Apple just isn't serving any real ads at the moment or if something else is wrong!  Oh well.

Thanks!

Jim

Comment: Apple should give you crash logs that you can symbolicate. What do they say?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the crash logs... where will I find them?